# bit Data type usage in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to capture Radio button values in db so i created table with datatype bit
  But the problem when am create stored Procedure as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Mt_Vacancy_mainPreference_insert

    (
    @post_name varchar(20),@preference varchar(20),gender bit,No_of_vac int
    )

AS
    Begin
    insert into Mt_Vacancy_mainPreference values(@post_name, @preference, @gender, @No_of_vac)
    end
    RETURN
```

It says Incorrect Sytax near gender
Must produce scal value
What is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `@` prefix for your last 2 parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to decorate the input variables;

`gender bit,No_of_vac int`

Should be

```
@gender bit, @No_of_vac int
```